# How to suppress error message from popen in lua

Tags: lua, popen

I need to run this command for a given PID on the host.

```
cmd = cat /proc/$PID/cgroup | grep -o  -e "docker-.*.scope"
io.popen(cmd)
```

When PID is a container, this is fine but once in a while I see,

```
cat: /proc/12345/cgroup: No such file or directory
```

So, I do the following:

```
f1 = io.open("/proc/" .. PID .. "/cgroup", "r+")
if (f1 == nil) then return end

local filename = "/proc/" .. PID .. "/cgroup"
local cmd = "test -f " .. filename .. " && cat " .. filename .. " grep -o -e "docker-.*.scope"
local f2 = io.popen(cmd)
```

Still I see the error message once in a while,
cat: /proc/5678/cgroup: No such file or directory

Notice I have the /proc/$PID/cgroup open and also do the `test -f` check in the command passed to popen.

My assumption is that between the  `test -f` and later `cat ...` command the proc entry for the process goes away and hence the popen command fails.

Is there something wrong in the code above? I just need to suppress this error message. What would be a good way to suppress this error message?

Answer (score 6):

Not much you can do on the Lua level, you just have to modify your `cat` command to redirect `stderr` into `/dev/null` as you'd do in bash on the terminal :)

```lua
local cmd = [[cat /proc/$PID/cgroup 2>/dev/null | grep -o  -e "docker-.*.scope"]]
```